# объект style как работает присваивание

Tags: javascript

```js
var div = document.getElementById('moving-div');
var placeHolder = document.createElement('div');
placeHolder.classList.add('anumber1');
placeHolder.style.height = div.offsetHeight + 'px';

var computedStyle = getComputedStyle(div, null);

placeHolder.style.marginTop = computedStyle.marginTop;
placeHolder.style.marginBottom = computedStyle.marginBottom;

placeHolder.style.backgroundColor = '#C2C49b';

document.body.insertBefore(placeHolder, div)

 div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.right = div.style.top = 0;
```

```html
Before Before Before

<div id="moving-div">
Text Text Text<br>
Text Text Text<br>
</div>

After After After
```

`div.style`  возвращает объект, который дает доступ к стилю элемента на чтение и запись.
Другими словами мы можем добавлять свои css стили;
Получается `right`  мы записали css свойство для топа; а топу мы присвоили 0; 
или `top` мы присвоили 0 а `right` присвоим `top` т.е. 0

```
div.style.right = div.style.top = 0;
```

Comment: Нет. Обоим присваивается значение 0. Присваивание право-ассоциативно https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: И style тут в общем-то ни при чём